# Can't change background image of custom uiButton for selected state

Tags: iphone, background, uibutton

With my code below, it seems that button is in normal state all the time (always green) eventhough i click on him.

```
UIButton *gumb = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     gumb.frame = CGRectMake(4, 40, 104, 37);
     gumb.tag=0;
    [gumb setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [gumb setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [gumb setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [gumb setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
```

If i set image for normal state to whiteButton and for seleted to greenButton then the button is always white and never green.

Comment: When you clicking on button, it will change state to **higlighted**. Not **selected** state. **Selected** state is used for tab-buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you set the state of the button as `selected` in the button click action

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
if(button.tag == 0)// in your case
{
button.selected = YES;
}
// Do something
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I thought iOS will take care of this.I have 3 buttons created in code, so i guess i must set the state of other 2 to "selected=NO" when one gets pressed.

Answer (score 4):

```
[gumb setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted]
```

use this one instead  of selected image

Answer (score 1):

I not sure if Selected state is only used for tab-buttons, 'cause I've tried like DixieFlatline did and sometimes did make the button image change. But method of tt.Kilew is definitely worth trying. Just try:
 [gumb setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"] forState: UIControlUIControlStateHighlighted]; and the button image will be changed on click.

Answer (score 0):

Code for setting selected state image:

```
[_button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Code for setting Normal state image:

```
[_button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```